# d(dx) exterior derivative in simple language?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, soft-question

I’m only learning the basics of analysis, so I have no understanding of exterior derivatives. I simply need clarification on my misconception using simple words.

I’m reading about second degree derivatives and found the following
$$d\left( dy\right) =d\left( f'\left( x\right) dx\right)= f''(x) dx * dx= f''\left( x\right) \left( dx\right) ^{2}$$

So I was thinking of expanding $d(f’(x)dx)$ to $f’’(x) * dx + f’(x) * d(dx)$. According to the axioms of exterior derivative, the latter part should equals to zero. However I was thinking $dx = 1 * \triangle(x)=(x-x_0)$, $d(dx) = d(x - x_0) = d(x) - d(x_0) = d(x)$
According to the definition of the exterior derivative, this is wrong. I’m confused with the misconception I have. Please help me clarify this.

Update on maybe a partial solution,

I’ve done some research on the web and found that maybe dx should be viewed as a constant. In that case d(dx) = 0. Can we view dx as a constant at all?

Comment: The way you use your $d$, it's really not the exterior derivative. (If it was, then $d(dy)$ shoud be zero). It would be easier if you give more context, so that we can guess what is really the $d$ that you are using.

Comment: @ArcticChar According to my textbook, as long as in the neighbor of x0, x has definition and $\triangle y$ can be written as $A * \triangle x + o(\triangle x)$, dy at x=x0 equals to $A*\triangle x$

Comment: Yes, so that's the definition of $dy$, but what's the definition of $d(dy)$? Now that $dy$ is not a function.

Comment: @ArcticChar The definition is what I wrote above( according to the textbook). It assumed that x and dx are independent, viewing “the first degree differential “as a function of x, and f is twice differentiable. Sorry, my wordings are weird, I’m translating from Chinese. By the way, I’m confused with what all these assumptions mean.

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry I forgot to add that “the first order differential” of y=f(x) is dy= f’(x) dx

Comment: As Arctic Char notes, this formalism is not precisely exterior differential calculus, but $d(dx) = 0$ is presumably a consequence of what happens for $f(x) = x$, since $f''(x) = 0$. <> Separately, if I'm reading right, the equation $1\, \Delta x = x - x_0$ tells us $d(x) = 1\, dx = dx$, as expected.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Still a bit confused why f(x) = x? Would you mind also explain why d(dx) = 0 in this case?

Comment: On closer inspection, I shouldn't say "$d(dx) = 0$ is a _consequence_...". The formalism gives $$d(f'(x)\, dx) = f''(x)\, (dx)^{2} + f'(x)\, d(dx),$$and if $f(x) = x$, this reduces to $d(dx) = d(dx)$, which is true whatever the definition of $d(dx)$. <> I'm not sure what implications this has for your question; it may be best to view $d(dx) = 0$ as a definition or axiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the notation $D$ instead of $d$, because $d$ refers to the exterior derivative, so that for any $C^2$ function $f$, we ALWAYS have $d^2f:=d(df)=0$. This is one of the standard theorems when learning about exterior derivatives.

What I think you're after is the second (and presumably higher order Frechet) derivatives $Df,D^2f,D^3f,\dots D^k f$. In this case, if $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is a sufficiently smooth function, then $D^kf$ is a tensor field of type $(0,k)$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$, so if we let $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ be the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$ then
\begin{align}
D^kf&=\sum_{I}(D^kf)[e_{i_1},\dots, e_{i_k}]\,dx^{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes dx^{i_k}\\
&=\sum_{I}\frac{\partial^kf}{\partial x^{i_1}\cdots \partial x^{i_k}}\,dx^{i_1}\otimes\cdots \otimes dx^{i_k}\\
&\equiv \sum_{I}\frac{\partial^kf}{\partial x^I}\,dx^{\otimes I}
\end{align}
(the first equality is really a matter of linear algebra, regarding how we can always expand a tensor in terms of a given basis), and in the last equal sign, I have just used shorthand notation.

Anyway, all this equality is saying is that at any given point $p\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $(D^kf)_p$ is a $(0,k)$-tensor on $\Bbb{R}^n$ whose value on a $k$-tuple of vectors $(h_1,\dots, h_k)\in\underbrace{\Bbb{R}^n\times\cdots \times \Bbb{R}^n}_{\text{$k$ times}}$ is
\begin{align}
(D^kf)_p[h_1,\dots, h_k]&=\sum_{I}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^I}(p)\cdot (h_1)^{i_1}\cdots (h_k)^{i_k}.
\end{align}
Of course, when the domain of $f$ is simply $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e $n=1$) then the linear algebra is particularly simple, because the tensor $D^kf$ is determined completely determined by the $k^{th}$ derivative $f^{(k)}$ in the sense that
\begin{align}
D^kf&=f^{(k)}\,dx^{\otimes k}
\end{align}
In this case, one may prefer to drop the tensor product symbol and simply write
\begin{align}
D^kf&=f^{(k)}\,(dx)^k
\end{align}
Once again, the meaning of this notation is that if you take derivatives at a point $p\in \Bbb{R}$ and evaluate on $(h_1,\dots, h_k)\in\underbrace{\Bbb{R}\times\cdots\times\Bbb{R}}_{\text{$k$ times}}$, then we get
\begin{align}
(D^kf)_p[h_1,\dots, h_k]&=f^{(k)}(p)\cdot h_1\cdots h_k.
\end{align}

---

Calculus is often pretty funny because we often introduce a lot of terminology:

1. The object $Df$ is often called the total derivative (in this case it just so happens that by identifying all the tangent spaces this equals the exterior derivative $df$).
2. The object $D^2f$ is often called the Hessian of $f$ and is denoted as $H_f$ (though people often think of the Hessian as a certain $n\times n$ matrix... but this only works if the target space of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$. If we change the target space to a higher dimensional space, then one is forced to abandon matrices and use the full force of multilinear algebra/tensors).